# Unresolved reference, type mismatch when trying to access an inner key

Tags: kotlin

I have this map:

````kotlin
{aws={foo={dev={account_id=1234}, pre={account_id=5678}, prod={account_id=9999}}, bar={dev={account_id=22222}, pre={account_id=33333}, prod={account_id=4444}}}}```
````

I can access `data.get("aws")` without issues. However, `data.get("aws").get("foo")` reports:

```
Unresolved reference. None of the following candidates is applicable because of receiver type mismatch: 
public inline operator fun <K, V> Map<out String, ???>.get(key: String): ??? defined in kotlin.collections
public operator fun MatchGroupCollection.get(name: String): MatchGroup? defined in kotlin.text
```

Why?

Comment: Consider the types. What type is `data`? Therefore, what type is `data.get("aws")`? What type would it need to be to be able to call `get("foo")` on it?

Comment: @gidds everything is a map

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first *get* returns a nullable, meaning the result of *map.get("aws")* can be a *map* or *null*. As you can not apply *.get(...)* to *null*, you must tell the compiler how to handle it:

```
val map = mapOf(
  "aws" to mapOf(
    "foo" to mapOf(
      "dev" to mapOf("account_id" to 1234),
      "pre" to mapOf("account_id" to 5678),
      "prod" to mapOf("account_id" to 9999),
    ),
    "bar" to mapOf(
      "dev" to mapOf("account_id" to 22222),
      "pre" to mapOf("account_id" to 33333),
      "prod" to mapOf("account_id" to 4444),
    )
  )
)

// if you are sure that a key "aws" exists, you can do this:
val foo = map.get("aws")!!.get("foo")
// foo is a Map<String, Map<String, Int>>

// If you are not sure that a key "aws" will exist:
val foo = map.get("aws")?.get("foo")
// foo is a Map<String, Map<String, Int>>?
```

See [Null Safety | Kotlin](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/null-safety.html)